# Query - limit the number of classes a teacher can teach

Tags: sql

I am working on my senior Project. A mini version of an online registration system and website. In the assumptions we want to limit the number of classes a teacher can teach in a semester to 3.

- `TblEmployee` contains: `emp_ID` (key), `can_Teach` (first 4 letters of topic).
- `TblCourse` contains: `course_ID` (Key), `course_Type` (first 4 letters of topic).
- `TblClass` contains: `ClassID` (Key), `emp_ID` (FK), `course_ID` (FK) semester (period of time)

So far this works fine in selecting the proper teacher that teaches that class:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblEmployee, tblCourse  
WHERE tblEmployee.canTeach = tblCourse.course_Type 
  AND tblClass.course_ID = ?
```

However I want to add to it that from `tblClass` if `emp_ID (COUNT)` < 3 to include those and exclude those greater than or equal to 3 (i.e. they will not show up in the drop down list.

I tried this but it did not work.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblEmployee, tblCourse 
WHERE tblEmployee.canTeach = tblCourse.course_Type 
  AND tblClass.course_ID = ? 
INNER JOIN (SELECT
                tblEmployee.emp_ID, tblClass.emp_ID 
            FROM 
                tblEmployee, tblClass 
            GROUP BY 
                tblClass.emp_ID 
            HAVING 
                count(*) < 3 AND tblClass.emp_ID = tblEmployee.emp_ID) 
  and semester = ?
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to clarify the title of your question!

Answer (score 0):

I would start on the sub query, slim it down, and make your syntax consistent.

```
   SELECT
   tblClass.emp_ID 
   FROM 
   tblClass 
   where semester = ?
   GROUP BY
   tblClass.emp_ID 
   HAVING count(tblClass.emp_ID) < 3
```

As I understand it, that is IDs which are in the table less than 3 times (teachers that are teaching less than 3 courses).

For your outer query, you want employees that meets its criteria but are also in the inner set.  Again, make your syntax consistent. Then try an IN.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblEmployee inner join tblCourse 
on tblEmployee.canTeach = tblCourse.course_Type 
where tblClass.course_ID = ?
and tblEmployee.emp_id 
in 
{
   SELECT
   tblClass.emp_ID 
   FROM 
   tblClass 
   where semester = ?
   GROUP BY
   tblClass.emp_ID 
   HAVING count(tblClass.emp_ID) < 3
}
```

See what that does.

Comment: Mike, you are amazing. Thanks for this. It works GREAT. This was what I ended up with : string commandText = "SELECT * FROM tblEmployee INNER JOIN tblCourse on tblEmployee.canTeach = tblCourse.course_Type where tblCourse.course_ID = ? and tblEmployee.emp_ID in (SELECT tblClass.emp_ID FROM tblClass GROUP BY tblClass.emp_ID HAVING count(tblClass.emp_ID) < 3)"; I need to move sem_Time up and perhaps set up a session variable to get it to work as right now it is NOT selected. Thus I get an error if I include semester.